# Always getting count zero using Parallel execution instead of forEach loop in c sharp

Tags: c#

I have a scenerio in which i have to call a third party server. Here on my side i have a array in which some record are exist, and every record in array need to send over third party call and get some byte of data and this returned data added in dictionary. initially i traverse array using forEach but it take more than 50 seconds, than i come over to use parallel.forEach to reduce time window, but at last dictionary count zero.
please help

```
 public void GenerateMultipleReport(ReportRenderDTO[] reportdetailCollection)
    {
        try
        {
           pdfMergedData = new List<Dictionary<string, byte[]>>();

                Parallel.ForEach(reportdetailCollection.Cast<ReportRenderDTO>(), async (reportdetails) =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => GetBytesFromServer(reportdetails));

                });  


            MergePDF(pdfMergedData);

        }
```

And Method GetBytesFromServer have below body :

```
 private void GetBytesFromServer(ReportRenderDTO reportdetails)
    {
        Dictionary<string, byte[]> pdfDataDicitionary = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        _logger.Debug("Method:GenerateMultipleReport()(BL), Role:generates a report from template ,Parameters:reportdetails, Return:void");
        string authorityName;
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var _jsonObject = (object[])jss.Deserialize(reportdetails.EOSParameters, typeof(object));
        Dictionary<string, object> _values = (Dictionary<string, object>)_jsonObject[0];
        Dictionary<string, string> _params = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        _values.Keys.ToList().ForEach(x => _params.Add(x, _values[x].ToString()));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reportdetails.AuthorityKode))
        {
            authorityName = _iEarchiveDocumentRepository.GetAuthorityName(reportdetails.AuthorityKode);
        }
        else
        {
            var userData = UserProfileInfo.GetUserProfile();
            authorityName = userData != null ? userData.myndighedData.Tekst : string.Empty;
        }


        Guid _documentId;
        _documentId = EOSPDFGenerator.Instance.Render(reportdetails.WorkFlowName, reportdetails.DocumentType, authorityName, _params);
        byte[] pdfData = this.RenderMultipleReport(_documentId.ToString(), reportdetails.DocumentType);
        pdfDataDicitionary.Add(reportdetails.WorkFlowName, pdfData);
        pdfMergedData.Add(pdfDataDicitionary);


    }
```

But always count of pdfMergedData is zero ....
Please tell me what is the problem.....

Comment: Aside from anything else, `List<T>` is *not* thread-safe... so you shouldn't be adding to it from multiple threads.

Comment: Is Parallel.ForEach Task aware? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

```
Parallel.ForEach(reportdetailCollection.Cast<ReportRenderDTO>(), reportdetails => GetBytesFromServer(reportdetails));
```

or even shorter

```
Parallel.ForEach(reportdetailCollection.Cast<ReportRenderDTO>(), GetBytesFromServer);
```

and use `ConcurrentDictionary` to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
Parallel.ForEach(reportdetailCollection.Cast<ReportRenderDTO>(), async (reportdetails) =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => GetBytesFromServer(reportdetails));
});
```

`Parallel.ForEach` is trying to execute the lambda parallel for different ranges of your array. But the individual executions return immediatly because you are using `async/await` inside. So the parallel foreach thinks it's done while your inside tasks are still running. Try it like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(reportdetailCollection.Cast<ReportRenderDTO>(), (reportdetails) =>
{
    GetBytesFromServer(reportdetails);
});
```

But if you do this you will be adding to a dictionary (inside `GetBytesFromServer`) from multiple threads, that will eventually fail. Try to synchronize this via a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it will probably eat up the improvement of `Parallel.ForEach`.